# cannot stop running debug in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

i am not being able to stop the debug process in my eclipse. i am trying to run the atl transformation but somehow failing all the time saying: `error: resource/..: null`, then i said, okay now i will debug and see where it is hanging, then i hit the debug button, now it is stuck at 57% and never stops, stop icon is even disabled. here is the scrennshot. how can i stop debugging? or another question, why is this happenning?

thanks for help!

[image]

Comment: you don't say which OS, so can't give specific info, but you're going to have to kill your eclipse task

Comment: @KevinDTimm, windows. if i kill eclipse task, the whole eclipse will be closed or what?

Comment: Yes, once it's done responding, it's your only choice.

Comment: @KevinDTimm, i would love to know why this is happening..

Comment: you can try a clean and recompile, then debug again, but after that your best bet is contact on an eclipse specific forum.